# Lebesgue Integration by Parts

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

As an example for a class presentation, I'm trying to determine the integral $\int_0^1 x^2D(X)dx$, where $D(x)$ is the Dirichlet function.

Since $D(x)=0$ a.e., $\int_0^1D(x)dx=0$. Additionally $\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}$. Our textbook is *The Lebesgue Integral for Undergraduates*. The formula we learned for integration by parts is $\int_a^bUv=U\cdot V|_a^b-\int_a^bVu$. We defined $U=\int_a^xu(t)dt$.

I'm very new to this integration approach (Lebesgue integral, not by parts). This is how I think this integral works out: Let $U=x^2$ and $v=D(x)$. Now, $\int_0^1x^2D(x)dx=(x^2\cdot0)|_0^1-\int_0^1(0\cdot2x)dx=0-0=0$.

I'm not totally convinced by my choices. Is there anything I should adjust?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. Why use integration by parts? Since $D(x) = 0$ ae. the integral is zero.

Comment: My professor just wanted an example that involved a function that isn't Riemann integrable. He suggested tacking on something split between the irrationals and something else.